# Angular 6: material-nav component - Template parse errors: Unexpected token '?' at column 20 in [isHandset$ | async ? 'dialog' : 'navigation']

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material, angular6

Here I am trying my very first angular 6 project for which I want to use material design for my project. I have created project successfully by taking reference from [material.angular.io][1] and added `material:nav` component for my nevigation which creates the navigation component files and in .ts file I have something like this:

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints, BreakpointState } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
 import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

 @Component({
   selector: 'my-nav',
   templateUrl: './my-nav.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./my-nav.component.css']
 })
 export class mynavComponent {

    isHandset$: Observable<BreakpointState> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset).pipe(map(result => result.matches));

    constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {}

  }
```

Which shows error like this while compiling the code from CLI

```
  Type 'Observable<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<BreakpointState>'. Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'BreakpointState'.
```

I have changed the `isHandSet$` like this

```
 isHandset$: Observable<BreakpointState> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset);
```

Which solves the compilation error but I am getting the **Template parse error**. I am getting this error in browser console

```
 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
 Parser Error: Unexpected token '?' at column 20 in [isHandset$ | async ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'] in ng:///AppModule/mynavComponent.html@4:2 ("
 class="sidenav"
 fixedInViewport="true"
 [ERROR ->][attr.role]="isHandset$ | async ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
 [mode]="isHandset$ | async ? 'over' : 's"): 
 ng:///AppModule/mynavComponent.html@4:2
```

My mynav.html contains

```
 <mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
   <mat-sidenav #drawer
   class="sidenav"
   fixedInViewport="true"
   [attr.role]="isHandset$ | async ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
   [mode]="isHandset$ | async ? 'over' : 'side'"
   [opened]="!(isHandset$ | async)">
   <mat-toolbar color="primary">Menu</mat-toolbar>
   <mat-nav-list>
   <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 1</a>
   <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 2</a>
   <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 3</a>
  </mat-nav-list>
 </mat-sidenav>
 <mat-sidenav-content>
  <mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <button
    type="button"
    aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
    mat-icon-button
    (click)="drawer.toggle()"
    *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
    <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <span>Application Title</span>
 </mat-toolbar>
</mat-sidenav-content>
```

Now the thing is how do I solve this issue. Is this is the issue of my browser? I am using Google chrome Version 66.0.3359.181 or something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enclose your Observables in `()`:

```
[attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
[mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
```

Comment: Current material schematic (as of 5/26/2018) is broken, but this tip fixes the issues, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Just change type of observable to **boolean** in your typescript
   file.
2. Match parentheses in your component html file

   - [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
   - [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"

here is the fix in Green Lines
[image]

Here is the main link of fix-https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/11448/commits/20306dbeed3fe7232ffb85ba1d9fd406f6885db2